# How to make bazel label absolute?

Tags: bazel

The Bazel [genquery](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery) documentation says:

> In contrast to the command line and other places in BUILD files, labels here are resolved relative to the root directory of the workspace. For example, the label :b in this attribute in the file a/BUILD will refer to the target //:b.

This means, in the `pkg` package I have to write `//pkg:b` instead of `b` or `:b`. However, this yields to user confusion, if the genquery is wrapped in a macro: The user must be aware of the implementation to know about the additional requirements, e.g:

```
my_cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  deps = ["foo", ":bar", "//baz:qux"],
)
```

If `my_cc_binary` wraps a genquery (in addition to a `cc_binary`) that operates on `deps`, the semantics of the lables change. How to make the specified relative labels absolute in a macro?

Answer (score 1):

bazel has a built in called native.package_relative_label which is at least available in macros

`str(native.package_relative_label(label))`

https://bazel.build/rules/lib/toplevel/native#package_relative_label

Answer (score 0):

Use [package_name](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#package_name) and [repository_name](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#repository_name):

```
def absolute_label(label):
    if label.startswith('@') or label.startswith('/'):
        return label
    if label.startswith(':'):
        return '@' + native.repository_name() + '//' + native.package_name() + label
    return '@' + native.repository_name() + '//' + native.package_name() + ':' + label
```